# Obtener resultados de un json usando javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Buenas gracias de ante mano .
Busco la manera de obtener las url de este **json**:

```
{
 "kind": "blogger#postList",
 "nextPageToken": "CgkIChjB-J3Q_isQ1vfW0eSImIxF",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "blog": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "published": "2017-11-28T05:58:00.001Z",
   "updated": "2017-11-28T05:58:39.837Z",
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/11/beauty-amateur-teen.html",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "title": "Beauty amateur teen",
   "author": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "displayName": "Unknown",
    "url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "image": {
     "url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv-U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s35"
    }
   },
   "replies": {
    "totalItems": "0",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "blog": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "published": "2017-11-27T17:58:00.001Z",
   "updated": "2017-11-27T17:58:41.191Z",
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/11/fingered-petite-japanese-doggystyle.html",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxx",
   "title": "Fingered petite japanese doggystyle banged",
   "author": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "displayName": "Unknown",
    "url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/xxxxxxxx",
    "image": {
     "url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv-U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s35"
    }
   }
```

Lo que deseo obtener son los enlaces de las entradas ejemplo:

```
http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/11/fingered-petite-japanese-doggystyle.html
```

El json lo obtengo llamando a esta url :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

En php es bastante fasil lograrlo pero lo necesito usando solo  **javasvript** o **jQuery** Y pues no tengo ni idea . espero su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las formas que existen para recorrer los `items` del `json` es usar el método [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) de **jQuery**, de la siguiente manera:

```js
var json = {
    "kind": "blogger#postList",
    "nextPageToken": "CgkIChjB-J3Q_isQ1vfW0eSImIxF",
    "items": [{
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "blog": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "published": "2017-11-28T05:58:00.001Z",
        "updated": "2017-11-28T05:58:39.837Z",
        "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/11/beauty-amateur-teen.html",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "title": "Beauty amateur teen",
        "author": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "displayName": "Unknown",
            "url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "image": {
                "url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv-U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s35"
            }
        },
        "replies": {
            "totalItems": "0",
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments"
        }
    }, {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "blog": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "published": "2017-11-27T17:58:00.001Z",
        "updated": "2017-11-27T17:58:41.191Z",
        "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/11/fingered-petite-japanese-doggystyle.html",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxx",
        "title": "Fingered petite japanese doggystyle banged",
        "author": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "displayName": "Unknown",
            "url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/xxxxxxxx",
            "image": {
                "url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zFdxGE77vvD2w5xHy6jkVuElKv-U9_9qLkRYK8OnbDeJPtjSZ82UPq5w6hJ-SA=s35"
            }
        }
    }]
}

$.each(json.items, function(index, dato){
    console.log(dato.url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Nota:** en el `json` que proporcionaste faltaba cerrar algunas llaves y corchetes.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta solo tengo una duda como obtengo el resultado de la url que contiene el json : https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx pra almacenarla en una variable algo asi como usar curl pero en jQuery

Comment: Te refieres a consumir la url ? podrías usar $.ajax() para eso, pero creo que debes crear una nueva pregunta ya que en esta preguntas como recorrer el json proporcionado, si deseas finalizamos esta pregunta creas la nueva y seguimos encontrando la solución desde allá.

Comment: bien plateare la nueva pregunta gracias